# R tidyverse - How to create a row summing the columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

Here is a sample of what my data look like:

| GRADE_LVL | COURSE_NAME | COURSE_CODE | STUDENT_GENDER | ETHNICITY | OUTCOME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | Physics | 03165 | Male | White | Pass |
| 12 | Physics | 03165 | Female | White | Pass |
| 12 | Physics | 03165 | Nonbinary | Black or African American | Pass |
| 9 | Algebra I | 02052 | Female | Multiracial | Pass |
| 10 | Algebra I | 02052 | Female | White | Fail |

I am trying to write a function that takes in filtering criteria as an argument, then outputs a tibble with counts for all gender/ethnicity combinations with a column that totals all rows and a row that totals all columns. I'm stuck on adding the row that sums all columns.

An example of what my output should look like:

|  | Hispanic | Native American | Asian | Black | White | Multiracial | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Male | 0 | 0 | 7 | 2 | 13 | 4 | 26 |
| Female | 1 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 12 | 3 | 20 |
| Nonbinary | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Total | 1 | 0 | 10 | 3 | 26 | 7 | 47 |

Here is my code:

```
middleSchool = c('07', '08')
algebra1 <- quo(COURSE_CODE_ALT == algebra1CourseCode)
ethnicCategories <- factor(c(
                              'Hispanic or Latino', 
                              'American Indian or Alaska Native',
                              'Asian',
                              'Native Hawaiian/Other Pacific Islander',
                              'Black or African American',
                              'White',
                              'Multiracial'
                            ))
genderCategories <- factor(c('Female', 'Male', 'Nonbinary'))

getDemographics <- function(filterConditions, gradeLevels) {
  COUR_APID_data |>
    filter( 
      {{filterConditions}} & 
      CURR_GRADE_LVL %in% gradeLevels
    ) |>
    mutate(
      Gender = factor(STUDENT_GENDER, levels = genderCategories),
      ethnicity = factor(ETHNIC_DESC, levels = ethnicCategories)
    ) |>
    count(Gender, ethnicity, .drop = FALSE) |>
    pivot_wider(names_from = ethnicity, values_from = n) |>
    mutate(Total = rowSums(select(., -c(Gender)))) |>
    add_row(summarize(
      across(where(is.numeric), sum),
      across(where(is.character), ~'Total')
    ))
}

report <- getDemographics(
  filterConditions = !!quo(!!algebra1),
  gradeLevels = middleSchool
)
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Error in `pick()`:
! Must only be used inside data-masking verbs like `mutate()`, `filter()`, and `group_by()`.
Backtrace:
 1. global getDemographics(filterConditions = !!quo(!!algebra1), gradeLevels = middleSchool)
 8. dplyr::pick("Hispanic or Latino")
```

I've been googling this for quite a while and have tried multiple solutions I've seen online, but none have run successfully for me so far.  The code is working up until the "Total row" was added. The "Total column" works, but as far as I can see `mutate` can only be used on columns.

Comment: Dean you don't need to quo() the algebra code twice

Comment: also it's good practice to include the dput() for your sample data. You've made 50+ questions you ought to know this by now. jpsmith's example df fails on your function because you've put grade level as a string, as well as many of the variable names not matching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can do it with `adorn_totals()` from the janitor package:

```
pacman::p_load(janitor, tidyverse)

getDemographics <- function(filterConditions, gradeLevels) {
  data |>
    filter( 
      {{filterConditions}} &
      GRADE_LVL %in% gradeLevels) |>
    mutate(
      Gender = factor(STUDENT_GENDER, levels = genderCategories),
      ethnicity = factor(ETHNIC_DESC, levels = ethnicCategories)) |>
    count(Gender, ethnicity, .drop = FALSE) |>
    pivot_wider(names_from = ethnicity, values_from = n, values_fill = 0) |> 
    adorn_totals(c("row", "col"))
}


getDemographics(
  filterConditions = !!quo(COURSE_CODE == '02052'),
  gradeLevels = c(09, 10)
)
```

Output:

```
    Gender Hispanic or Latino American Indian or Alaska Native Asian
    Female                  0                                0     0
      Male                  0                                0     0
 Nonbinary                  0                                0     0
     Total                  0                                0     0
 Native Hawaiian/Other Pacific Islander Black or African American White
                                      0                         0     1
                                      0                         0     0
                                      0                         0     0
                                      0                         0     1
 Multiracial Total
           1     2
           0     0
           0     0
           1     2
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution I went with. I'm just surprised that there isn't an easier solution already somewhere in base R or tidyverse. It seems odd to have to install a new package.

Comment: there are ways of doing it with base R (see jpsmith's answer) and tidyverse, it's just not one line (very few things are!)

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to filter your data based on an input variable (`filtervar`, ie,`COURSE_NAME`) and value (`filterval`, ie, "Physics"), you should be able to simply use `table` and `addmargins` to create what you want, wrapping it in `as.data.frame.matrix`:

```
myfun <- function(data, filtervar, filterval){
  fdata <- data %>% filter({{filtervar}} %in% filterval) %>% select(STUDENT_GENDER, ETHNICITY)
  as.data.frame.matrix(addmargins(table(fdata)))
}

# with sample data

myfun(df, COURSE_NAME, "Physics")

#           Black or African American White Sum
# Female                            0     1   1
# Male                              0     1   1
# Nonbinary                         1     0   1
# Sum                               1     2   3
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "GRADE_LVL COURSE_NAME COURSE_CODE STUDENT_GENDER ETHNICITY OUTCOME
12 Physics 03165 Male White Pass
12 Physics 03165 Female White Pass
12 Physics 03165 Nonbinary 'Black or African American' Pass
9 'Algebra I' 02052 Female Multiracial Pass
10 'Algebra I'  02052   Female  White   Fail", h = TRUE)
```